# Why invalid syntax in line 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

Whats the syntax error in line 5?? I have tried everything already... Anybody knows?

```
print ("a. Dolar --> Euro\nb. Euro --> Dolar\n")
opti = input("Pick an option: ")
val = float(input("Enter value: ")

if opti == "a":
    convr = 0.895
    print (str(convr * val) + " Euros")
elif opti == "b":
    convr = 1/0.895
    print (str(convr * val) + " Dollars")
else:
    print ("NOT ALLOWED!")
```

Comment: Because you forgot a `)` on line 3.

Comment: Count your `(` and `)`. you're missing one...

Comment: Seriously??? Im so lazy

Comment: I will pay more attention. Im promisse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your brackets

```
val = float(input("Enter value: ")
```

should be

```
val = float(input("Enter value: "))
```

Comment: Thanks! :D (Im lazy...)